Excel Combine Column A from Multiple Worksheets
Currently using Excel 2021 Home Office. I have a sheet named 'Total'.
Goal: Display all the words from Column A , in multiple sheets from Sheet1 to Sheet9.
So it will display words all from Column A into one large concatenated column.

Car
Furniture
Grass
Tree
Ocean...

Originally, had this equation below with TOCOL and VSTACK, but it does not work anymore for some reason (after copying to GoogleSheets and back into Excel). Our office does not allow VBA or PowerPivot. Implement with RangedSheets, instead of listing all 10. Only attempting excel equations. There is a way to do it. Trying to remember.
=_xlfn.TOCOL(_xlfn.VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet9!A1:A99),1)


You could try using the following formula:
=FILTERXML("<m><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",1,Sheet1:Sheet9!A1:A99)&"</b></m>","//b")


The above formula does work here, however it has some limitations because of the TEXTJOIN() function, therefore one can use Power Query here as well. Where all the data in the sheets needs to converted to Structured References aka Tables and then paste the following m-code in a blank query to import it back to Excel:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    Filter = Table.SelectRows(Source, each not Text.Contains([Name], "Query")),
    Expand = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Filter, "Content", {"Header"}, {"Header"}),
    RemoveCol = Table.RemoveColumns(Expand,{"Name"})
in
    RemoveCol




collect words with TEXTJOIN

caveat


If the resulting string exceeds 32767 characters (cell limit), TEXTJOIN returns the #VALUE! error.


please let me know if you get this error


add start/end tokens for each word with SUBSTITUTE using instance number based on index for the word

extract each word with MID, getting start/end token positions with FIND

this works under Mac as well


=LET(
    r, Sheet1:Sheet9!A1:A99,
    csv, "," & TEXTJOIN(",", , r) & ",",
    num_words, COUNTA(r),
    idx, SEQUENCE(num_words),
    MID(
        csv,
        FIND("<", SUBSTITUTE(csv, ",", "<", idx)) + 1,
        FIND(">", SUBSTITUTE(csv, ",", ">", idx + 1)) -
            FIND("<", SUBSTITUTE(csv, ",", "<", idx)) - 1
    )
)


